# Runing sp_Blitz on a database as a user - Work arounds please

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitz

I am a DBA on many servers running SQL Server and am a big user of sp_Blitz. The issue I have is that I am still to maintain a database that is migrating to a VM on AWS.

The issue is that I'm not permitted DBA access. I can only now connect with user credentials.

But I still have desire to monitor as much as possible. Even simple stuff like check the backups have been run. So I can now only run minimal queries. Obviously I can't install sp_Blitz as it creates stored procedures.

But I do have full DBO to the database before it migrates over. Yes I can install sp_Blitz in that database, as it would be dbo.sp_Blitz. But I won't have the permission to then run it as a user.

Any suggestions or pointers on how I can get it (or open to alternatives) into the database in a way that I can execute when I'm just a user?

Comment: this looks like it is what you are trying to do: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188192/minimum-permissions-required-to-run-sp-blitz

Answer (score 2):

sp_Blitz is really for database administrators, not users. If you don't have DBA permissions, sp_Blitz won't be a good fit.

If you want to skip specific checks that you don't have permission for, you can use [the SkipChecks feature described in the documentation](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/main#skipping-checks-or-databases), but if you're not a DBA, you're probably going to have to do a lot of skipping just to get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get someone else who is a sysadmin to recreate/modify the sp_blitz stored procedures they could add execute as "blah" to the stored procedure definition and then grant you exec permission to the SP. When you run the sp_blitz sp it would then execute in the context of the specified user (replace blah with something sensible) who presumably does have the right permissions and return you the normal results.

For more details you could look at Books on Line or this article
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1227/sql-server-execute-as/